# PHP bind_param with to equal arrays, but only one work

Tags: php, arrays, binding, prepared-statement

I have followed many forums records.
And I have two different ways to build an array for binding, but why the first way dosent work ?

```
<?php
class BindParam{ 
private $values = array(), $types = ''; 

public function add( $type, &$value ){ 
    $this->values[] = $value; 
    $this->types .= $type; 
} 

public function get(){ 
    return array_merge(array($this->types), $this->values); 
} 
} 
class db
{
....

$stmt = $conn->prepare(@"SELECT xy FROM xx WHERE yy = ? AND zz = ?");

$bindParam = new BindParam(); 

$typ ="";
$par;

for( $i = 0; $i < count($params); $i++)
{
    $bindParam->add($params[$i][0], $params[$i][1]);//for example 1
    $typ .= $params[$i][0];//for example 2
    $par[] = $params[$i][1];//for example 2
}
echo "Example1: ";
print_r($bindParam->get());

echo "<br>Example2: ";
$bind_names[] = $typ;
for ($i=0; $i<count($par);$i++) 
{
    $bind_name = 'bind' . $i;
    $$bind_name = $par[$i];
    $bind_names[] = &$$bind_name;
}

print_r($bind_names);


$return = call_user_func_array(array($stmt,'bind_param'),$bind_names);
//$return = call_user_func_array(array($stmt,'bind_param'),$bindParam->get());
echo "<br>Binding return: ".$return;

.
.
.
}
```

the output is for example1:

Example1: Array ( [0] => ss [1] => test [2] => test )
Example2: Array ( [0] => ss [1] => test [2] => test )
Binding return: 1

the output is for example2:

Example1: Array ( [0] => ss [1] => test [2] => test )
Example2: Array ( [0] => ss [1] => test [2] => test )
Warning: Parameter 2 to mysqli_stmt::bind_param() expected to be a reference, value given in...
Binding return:

the commented-out code (//$return = (example2)) dosent work.

Comment: what is count($params)?

Comment: sorry its a array and a parameter for the class db the function get a query string and a param array:                      $params = array
(
 array("s","bb"),
 array("s","pw")
); OUTPUT IS : Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => s [1] => test ) [1] => Array ( [0] => s [1] => test ) )

Comment: alternative i can use $typ .= substr(strtolower(gettype($params[$i][1])), 0, 1); and dont need a multi array, but think its bether so as paramlist

Comment: it is normally more reliable to use 'bindValue' rather than 'bindParam', as any value, even a calculated one can be used with 'bindValue'. i.e. do not use 'bindParam' unless you have to, is a useful guideline.